# how to read excel file by browsing the file using jsp servlets

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am working on a project where i need to do the following things:

1. click a button to browse and read excel file and the data gets uploaded to the database
2. data should be displayed in a grid like view and must contain editable fields.
3. there should some way to choose 1st row and a download button upon which on clicking creates a new excel file which contains the selection of 1st and Nth row.

I am using JFileChooser to browse file and read data but being a swing component is working on server only. not from any remote system.

Is there any other way around ??

Comment: Lookup Apache POI. Its a Java library for reading Microsoft Office documents.

Comment: @developerwjk Thankyou for your reply, so far i have to success to read excel file and insert data in database by hard coding the file path, but in my application user is suppose to browse file in its system and choose excel file to insert data. Any Help how to browse and read excel file using jsp.

Comment: You need a HTML fileupload box in a form and to use apache commons file upload library on the server side to handle saving the file to server. Then you can read it in Java from where you store the uploaded file.